# Memory report confusion shown by top and htop commands?

Tags: mysql, memory, memory-leaks, htop

I'm on Slicehost 256 plan running one single Rails app on Ubuntu Hardy 64 bit server.

This is the shot taken using top command sorted by memory% (Shift+M)
[Memory by top http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7d35d548bf.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7d35d548bf.png)

And this is the screenshot taken while running htop command sorted by memory% used.
[Memory by htop http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f598fea0da.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f598fea0da.png)

The memory consumed by mysql using top shows 3.8% but the htop shows around 17 processes each eating up around 3.2% of memory.

Whats the difference between those stat shown by top and htop??

Is mysql eating up my memory as shown by htop??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like htop defaults to showing you the threads view. You can get the same effect in top by pressing shift-H. There is one mysql process using 3.2% memory and 17 threads.

Alternatively, you can [make htop display only a single line per process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124976/htop-displays-identical-program-in-multiple-lines), like the default behavior in top.